# Cannot see my icon in my MenuItem

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have `WPF` application with simple `Menu`:

```
<Menu Name="menuColor" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <MenuItem Name="menuItemHeader" Header="Color" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemHeaderDefaultStyle}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Name="ButtonImageColor" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/update_black.ico" Height="12" Width="12"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
        <MenuItem Name="miBlue" Header="Blue" Click="miBlue_Click" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemDefaultStyle}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Name="miBlueImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/ok_mark2.png" Height="12" Width="12"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

So in my title bar i have this `Color` text and after its clicked i have the option `Blue`.
So instead of this `Color` text i want to add `icon` and currently i cannot see my icon.
I also try to remove the `Header="Color"` but still i cannot see my `icon`.

Update:

This is the `Style` i am using in my `MenuItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemHeaderDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid Background="{DynamicResource AppBackground}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!-- ContentPresenter to show an Icon if needed -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Icon"/>

                            <!-- Glyph is a checkmark if needed for a checkable menu -->
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="GlyphPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanelpath" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,2 L0,4.8 L2.5,7.4 L7.1,2.8 L7.1,0 L2.5,4.6 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- Content for the menu text etc -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  x:Name="HeaderHost"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"/>

                            <!-- Content for the menu IGT -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2"
                                                  Margin="8,1,8,1"
                                                  x:Name="IGTHost"
                                                  ContentSource="InputGestureText"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <!-- Arrow drawn path which points to the next level of the menu -->
                            <Grid Grid.Column="3"
                                      Margin="4,0,6,0"
                                      x:Name="ArrowPanel"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- The Popup is the body of the menu which expands down or across depending on the level of the item -->
                            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder"
                                            Background="White"
                                            BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}" 
                                            BorderThickness="0" 
                                            Padding="0"
                                            Width="80">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                        <!-- StackPanel holds children of the menu. This is set by IsItemsHost=True -->
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <!-- These triggers re-configure the four arrangements of MenuItem to show different levels of menu via Role -->
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- Role = TopLevelHeader : this is the root menu item in a menu; the Popup expands down -->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="2" TargetName="Col0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" TargetName="Col3"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="IGTHost"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Role = TopLevelItem :  this is a child menu item from the top level without any child items-->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Role = SubMenuHeader : this is a child menu item which does not have children -->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Role = SubMenuItem : this is a child menu item which has children-->
                        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,0,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ArrowPanel"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" TargetName="SubMenuPopup"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- If no Icon is present the we collapse the Icon Content -->
                        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- The GlyphPanel contains the CheckMark -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="GlyphPanel"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="Icon"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Using the system colors for the Menu Highlight and IsEnabled-->
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" TargetName="Border"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HighlightedText}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AppBackground}" TargetName="Border"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SolidMenuFontBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AppBackground}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Is `MenuItemDefaultStyle` created by you? Can you show its xaml?

Comment: Please see my update